# After install ati radeaon drivers when I open tty using (Ctrl+Alt+F1) the monitor shuts down

Tags: 14.04, graphics, amd-graphics, tty

After installing the X.org drivers using the command `sudo apt-get install flgrx gksudo` or something close - here is a [link](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/ubuntu/x-updates) for the ppa page - when I try any tty from <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd> the monitor shuts down (It opens again after I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.
Also the monitor shuts down in booting immediately after the splash screen appears.

- Ubuntu version : 14.04
- Graphics card : AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series.

Answer (score 1):

With that radeon series you should use the radeon driver instead of the closed source catalyst. There is no gain from using the closed source driver.

Comment: should I just unistall 'flgrx'?

Comment: Yes. I recommend that. The built in radeon driver is good. You could upgrade ubuntu to get a newer version of the radeon driver if it is lacking some functionality.

Comment: after I uninstalled flgrx. Now the monitor is blank even in the gui mode!

Comment: This means your monitor does not show anything after bootup? Or does it show nothing after Ctrl+Alt+F1 ?

Comment: it does not show anything while booting and when I press ctrl + alt + f1. but I reinstalled Ubuntu and now the resolution is very low, the graphics looks bad, and apt-get does not work without a vpn but I cannot install the vpn client v_v.